# Allow comment upvotes on election page

Tags: feature-request, comments, upvotes, moderator-election

This is the page where I would like to be able to upvote comments:

https://stackoverflow.com/election

This question was [previously answered](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/245124/can-too-upvote-comments-under-an-election-nomination/252916#252916) in 2015, but doesn't make a lot of sense to me (or to other commenters):

> Voting for comments has been disabled during the nomination phase for
>   now. We want to make sure that we are at consistent when it comes to
>   elections.

Is it still "for now"?